# Etymology of the word 'galligu'?

Tags: etymology

I came across a word in an chemistry lecture which appears in plenty of places but none explaining where the word came from. The word in question is 'galligu'

From [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/galligu),

> **Galligu** 
>   1. The insoluble waste products of the Leblanc process.

It seems as if the word appeared out of nowhere and nobody questioned it, which is somewhat strange (though if I try hard enough I'll probably find it's not unheard of) for a science-related term. I have a hunch it may be somehow related to French, but nary a source to be found. Any help?

Example usage -
http://www.nce.co.uk/the-perils-of-galligu/1228052.article

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the people of Lancashire created the moniker *[galligu](https://books.google.com/books?id=5uC0NNam4FUC&q=%22galligu%22&dq=Moreover%20noisom%20%22galligu%22%20Lancashire&hl=en&sa=X&ei=H_hTVczyBYn7yASys4GACQ&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAg)* for the stinky stuff sometime before 1836:

> Even after Gossage had developed in 1836 his towers for the
>   condensation of byproduct hydrochloric acid, whose fumes were poisoning the countryside in the
>   neighborhood of every alkali plant...Moreover, the process continued
>   to waste valuable sulphur, to say
>   nothing of calcium and large amounts of unchanged coal, in the form of
>   a noisome mud that the inhabitants of ***Lancashire*** expressively baptized
>   '***galligu***', which added to the injury of loss the insult of costly disposal.
>
> *THE CAMBRIDGE ECONOMIC HISTORY OF EUROPE (published as early as [1941](https://books.google.com/books?id=HjvsAAAAMAAJ&q=%22galligu%22&dq=%22galligu%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PfxTVdPCFo-3yATH8oDgCg&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAw)) **emphasis** mine*

It seems to be an *[onomatopoeic](https://books.google.com/books?id=a5c4AAAAIAAJ&q=%22galligu%22&dq=%22galligu%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=evlTVaSqCs6XygSzmYHQCg&ved=0CBwQ6AEwADg8)*:

> In Widnes the evil-smelling mud was known as "galligu" an onomatopoeic
>   term to indicate its slushy consistency and general nauseous nature.
>
> *Smokeless Air - Issues 131-134 - Page 144*

Possible influences on the name:

> *[Gall](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gall)*:
>
> 2.2 Used to refer to something bitter or cruel:
>
> *[goo](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/goo)*
>
> 1.0 A sticky or slimy substance.
>   ODO

Comment: I would be wary of attributing "likely sources" by apparent similarity alone.